# How can i return new object using a method that modifies a data field without messing with the data field of the object used to call that method

Tags: java, list

```
public final class myClass {
final List<Integer> mylist;

    public myClass(List<Integer> l) {
    this.mylist = l;
}
    myClass method(){

for (int i=0;i<mylist.size();i++) {

    mylist.set(i, mylist.get(i)*2);

}
        return new myClass(mylist);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> l1=new ArrayList<Integer>();

        l1.add(2);
        l1.add(4);

        myClass t=new myClass(l1);

        System.out.println(t.method().mylist);
        System.out.println(t.mylist);

    }

}
```

how can i use the method and return a new myclass object without changing the t object's list elements
OUTPUT:
[4, 8]
[4, 8]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'mylist' is an object (vs. a primitive, like 'long', 'int', etc). That means any variable is a **reference** to an object (a 'pointer' if you're coming from C). It's like a treasure map to the treasure, and you've created a new object that gets a copy of a treasuremap, but you haven't copied the treasure at all.

The only way to do that is to... copy the treasure. You'd have to create an entirely new list. Somehow, `new ArrayList<Integer>()` would need to be executed twice (either the same line as least twice or that code needs to appear in at least two places).

There isn't a suitable built in system in java to just copy anything (there is the 'clone' system but.. you don't want to use it).

Note that lists need not be immutable. From a style perspective it probably makes more sense if the `myClass` class takes full control if its fields and no longer lets you pass a list in, or that it makes a copy of the input list (`new ArrayList<Integer>(someList);` will make a complete copy).